# Openvpn-server: Execute a script when on a failed connection?

Tags: scripting, openvpn

Good morning,

I was wondering if It was possible to setup something to execute a script when someone tried to connect but the TLS check failed (When someone who is not supposed to connected try to°

I would like to be able to execute a script to send me an email.